# Create arrows in matplotlib using annotate

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm annotating my plot with

```
plt.annotate(
    '30.2',
    xy=(3, y),
    xycoords='data',
    xytext=(3, y - 5),
    textcoords='data',
    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', arrowstyle="->")
)
```

It creates downward arrows as expected but they are not completely vertical.

If I change `'30.2'` to a en empty string `''`, they are vertical.

How can I make sure the arrows are vertical no matter how long the text string is?

Comment: can you show us an SSCCE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of text alignment. Try this:

```
plt.annotate(
    '30.2',
    xy=(3, y),
    xycoords='data',
    xytext=(3, y - 5),
    textcoords='data',
    horizontalalignment='center',
    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', arrowstyle="->")
)
```